# PhalconPHP bind params and oerder by

Tags: sql-order-by, phalcon

Here is the code what I've tried

```
$conditions = "category = :id: AND status = :status: ORDER BY :order: LIMIT 3";

$parameters = array(
    "id" => $cat_id,
    "status" => 1,
    "order" => "title ASC",
);

$posts = Posts::find(array(
    $conditions,
    "bind" => $parameters
));
```

Everything is fine except order by. Can you please help me to find out the proper way to use order by in PhalconPHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"bind" and "order" are [separate parameters](http://docs.phalconphp.com/pl/latest/reference/models.html#finding-records):

```
$conditions = "category = :id: AND status = :status:";

$parameters = array(
    "id" => $cat_id,
    "status" => 1,
);

$posts = Posts::find(array(
    "conditions" => $conditions,
    "bind" => $parameters,
    "order" => "title ASC",
    "limit" => 3
));
```

this is clean and reliable approach - this way you have in your conditions only striclty **conditions**. You can change your limit/order based on request params without touching condition string.